# How are java increment statements evaluated in complex expressions

Tags: java, post-increment, operator-precedence

What is the output of the following code:

```
int x = 2;  
x += x++ * x++ * x++;  
System.out.println(x);
```

I understand that `++variableName` is pre-increment operator and the value of `variableName` is incremented before it is used in the expression whereas `variableName++` increments its value after the expression is executed. What I want to know is - how does this logic apply here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [a += a++ \* a++ \* a++ in Java. How does it get evaluated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369393/a-a-a-a-in-java-how-does-it-get-evaluated)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its easier to see the what is going on with x = 1 instead of 2. The output for `x=1` is 7.

The key to the understanding of this is in JLS [15.7.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2) which states that the every operand is fully evaluated before any part of the operation is performed.

> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.

Thus, x++ (each of 3 times, left to right with appropriate precedence which isn't an issue here) is evaluated, then the operation * is evaluated and assigned to the original value.

```
x = 1 + (1 * 2 * 3)
```

If x starts out with 2, you get:

```
x = 2 + (2 * 3 * 4)
```

Unlike in C, this is well defined in Java and will behave the same on each invocation in any runtime.

<sup><sub>Associated ideone if anyone wants to run it for themselves: https://ideone.com/Y2qcJ6</sub></sup>