# Value of y = x + x++ in Java

Tags: java, increment, post-increment

Say we have Java code below:

```
int x = 1;
int y = x + x++;
```

'Cause the precedence of "postfix-increment" operator is higher than "add" operator. I think `x++` should be calculate and evaluated first. Then it comes to `x + (x++)`. So the `y` should be "new_x(2) + 1 = 3".

Though it turns out "2" instead of "3". Any ideas? Thanks.

---

This question is **greatly** different from [Is there a difference between x++ and ++x in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java). That question mentions nothing about the `operator precedence`.

Someone has explained that expression is read from left to right. Does it conflict with the precedence of those operators?

Just as I mentioned before, I think x++ should be calculated first. It seems that I mess up with the "evaluation" and "calculation".

Comment: Expressions are read from left to right. `x + x++;` --> `1 + x++`. And when `x = 1`, `x++` will return 1. So the result is `1 + 1 = 2`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Would you have prefered this dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13369393/1743880

Comment: It's not a bad one, but perhaps a better one could be found, else you could always answer it. A good answer needs to talk about associativity and precedence. I liked your comment a lot.

Comment: `x++` is evaluated first, yes, but result of `x++` is the value of `x` prior to evaluation.

Comment: @Bathsheba There are a lot of duplicates out there, the  one I linked to actually talks about the same case `y = y * y++;`.

Comment: `x++` is the same as `(x = x + 1)` **but** the assignment happens *after* the current statement (that's why it is called a [*post-increment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) operator). So, `y = x + x++` is the same as `y = 1 + 1; x = x + 1;` and thus you get `x` equal to `2` **and** `y` equal to `2`.

Comment: @Tunaki: for me, a duplicate is a duplicate, not an approximate match. And y = y * y++ is different from x = y * y++.

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/q/18991306/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki The associativity of `*` is left-to-right. Assume `y = y * y++`. Yes, according to associativity, y is evaluated first. But what about the precedence, 'cause ++ still has the higher precedence. Why y++ cannot be evaluated first?

Comment: @StephenW Take a look at the other question I linked to (the comment just above). From it: *The confusion stems from the fact that the operands are evaluated from left to right. This is done first, before any attention is paid to operator precedence/order of operations.*

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks. I will look at it at once.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between x++ and ++x is quite evident and known. ++ can be used as preadd (Add 1 and then use x ) or postadd (use x and add 1).
Check this out.

As tested and seen

```
1. x + x++ will give 2
2. x + ++x will give 3
3. x++ + x will give 3
4. ++x + x will give 4
```

Now the interesting case here is 2nd and 4th which basically explains pre-add operator.

In these cases, the value of x is incremented first and then used in both the places.

However in case of test 2 the first operand i.e. x is already used up for addition so the answer is 3

while in the test 4 the operand x is first incremented and used in both the operands. This happens because the expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score -1):

x++ would first return x then increment x.

++x would increment x first then return x.

Therefore :

```
int y = x + x++; //y (2) = x(1) + x(1, then becomes 2 right after)

int y = x + ++x; //y (3) = x(1) + x(becomes 2 before being returned)
```

Comment: Doesn't explain why the answer is 2.

Comment: The "therefore" does not follow.